# Rich Text editor for multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

In one of our apps, we are building a custom rich text editor where the toolsets (bold, italics, bullets .. etc) are applicable to multiple text boxes. We are almost done building the same. It has a lot of feature limitations that prevents it from behaving like a standard Rich text editor like TinyMCE. 
Looking for help or references in case some one else has worked on a similar problem before. Thanks for your help in advance.

[image: The screenshot of the requirement]

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken there is a way to control whether you display the TinyMCE toolbar.
+ you can limit the tools on the toolbar to be exactly the above.
so you can hook to the focus of all text boxes and on each focus show the right toolbar